# Find the number of \n before a given word in a long string

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a long string:

```
string = 'Idnum\rId\nkey: maturity\n2\nmaturity\rpara1\rpara2\n1Y\r0\r0\n2Y\r0\r0'
```

Now I want to find out the number of  `\n` before the word  `\nmaturity` (is unique in the string and we can see the answer is 2).

Here is the motivation of this question, if you cannot understand what I say below, just ignore it and focus on the question above.

I want to use `pandas` to read the `data` (I am not sure for the structure of `data`, may be a csv):

[image]

and use the syntax:

```
value = pandas.read_csv(data, sep = '\t', skiprows = 3).set_index('maturity')
```

to skip first `3` rows before `maturity` to obtain the table like:
[image]

So I need to find out the row number of `maturity` to determine how many rows I should skip. But what I only know for `data` is

```
data.getvalue() = 'Idnum\rId\nkey: maturity\n2\nmaturity\rpara1\rpara2\n1Y\r0\r0\n2Y\r0\r0'
```

(`\n` is changing the line and `\r` is changing the cell). So I have to naively find the number of `\n` before `maturity` to determine the row number of `maturity` in the original table (or `data`).

So, if you are familiar with above structure, could you tell me how to find the row number of `maturity` in the `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

- First `split` the string with '\nmaturity' as separator and take the first (thus left of the first found item).
- Than use `count` to count the number of '\n's.

Untested:

```
string = 'Idnum\rId\nkey: maturity\n2\nmaturity\rpara1\rpara2\n1Y\r0\r0\n2Y\r0\r0'
stringUntilMaturity = string.split('\nmaturity')[0]
counts = stringUntilMaturity.count('\n')
```