# Use pandas to read the csv file with several uncertain factors

Tags: pandas, csv

I have asked the related question of string in: [Find the number of \n before a given word in a long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292729/find-the-number-of-n-before-a-given-word-in-a-long-string/54292795#54292795]). But this method cannot solve the complicate case I happened to. Thus I want to find out a solution of `Pandas` here.

I have a csv file (I just represent as a `string`):

```
csvfile = 'Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0'
```

[image]

I want to use the `pandas`：

```
value = pandas.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', skiprows = 3).set_index('maturity')
```

to obtain the table like:

[image]

and set the first columan `maturity` as index.

But there are several uncertain factors in the csvfile:

1.`.set_index('maturity')`, the key `maturity`
 of index is included in the row `key: maturity`. Then I should find the row `key: xxxx` and obtain the string `xxxx`

2.`skiprows = 3`: the number of skipped rows before the title:
[image]

is uncertain. The csvfile can be something like:

`'Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\n\n\n\n\n\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0'`

I should find the row number of title (namely the row beginning with `xxxx` found in the row`key: xxxx`).

3.`sep = '\t'`: the csvfile may use `space` as separator like:

`csvfile = 'Idnum  Id\nkey: maturity\n2\nmaturity para1  para2\n1Y  0  0\n2Y  0  0'`

So is there any general code of `pandas` to deal with the csvfile with above uncertain factors?

Actually the string:

```
csvfile = 'Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0'
```

is from a `StringIO`: `data`

```
data.getvalue() = 'Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0'
```

I am not familiar with this structure and even I want to obtain a table of original `data` without any edition by using:

```
value = pandas.read_csv(data, sep = '\t')
```

There will be a error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file line by line, collecting the necessary information and then pass the remainder to `pd.read_csv` with the appropriate arguments:

```
from io import StringIO
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('data.csv') as fh:
    key = next(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('key:'), fh)).lstrip('key:').strip()
    header = re.split('[ \t]+', next(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(key), fh)).strip())
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fh.read()), header=None, names=header, index_col=0, sep=r'\s+')
```

Example for data via `StringIO`:

```
fh = StringIO('Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0')

key = next(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('key:'), fh)).lstrip('key:').strip()
header = re.split('[ \t]+', next(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(key), fh)).strip())
df = pd.read_csv(fh, header=None, names=header, index_col=0, sep=r'\s+')
```

Comment: here you input a csv file `data.csv`. My original `data` is a `StringIO`  and the `csvfile` is actually `data.getvalue() `. Then how to read a  `StringIO` `data` line by line as you showed?

Comment: by the way, even I only want to obtain a table of original `data` without any edition. I use syntax `value = pandas.read_csv(data, sep = '\t')`, which is not allowed. Do you know why?

Comment: @A.Oreo In case your input is present as a `StringIO` you can do exactly the same as above, replacing `fh` with the `StringIO` instance Of course, when feeding the remainder to `read_csv` you would only pass the instance and not wrap it again by another `StringIO`. I don't understand what you mean by your second comment ("a table of original `data`"). Can you provide more details?

Comment: `data = StringIO('Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0')`, so you mean I can use the syntax: `with open(data) as StringIO:`?   And I Used `value = pandas.read_csv(dada, sep = '\t')`, there will be an error. I just want to obtain the table of `data` without any modification.

Comment: @A.Oreo You should replace the whole `with` statement by `fh = StringIO(...)`. Please see my updated answer. The error probably occurred because initially I've assumed a space between `"key:"` and the actual key. I adjusted that in my answer, now it works with or without additional space.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind reading the csv file twice you can try doing something like:

```
from io import StringIO
csvfile = 'Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0'

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvfile), sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
skiprows = len(data)
pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvfile), sep='\t', skiprows=skiprows)
```

same for you other example:

```
csvfile = 'Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\n\n\n\n\n\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0'

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvfile), sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
skiprows = len(data)
pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvfile), sep='\t', skiprows=skiprows)
```

This assumes that you know the `sep` of the file

Also if you want to find the key:

```
csvfile = 'Idnum\tId\nkey:maturity\n2\n\n\n\n\n\nmaturity\tpara1\tpara2\n1Y\t0\t0\n2Y\t0\t0'
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvfile), sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
key = [x.replace('key:','') for x in data[0] if x.find('key')>-1]
skiprows = len(data)

pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvfile), sep='\t', skiprows=skiprows).set_index(key)
```